# Which tool can upload videos to multiple sites (with scheduling, queueing)?

Tags: video, youtube, upload

Are there software that lets you upload videos to video hosting sites?

Video sites it should support:

- YouTube
- Google Video
- Megavideo
- ...

Features it should support:

- Scheduling upload
- Queuing of videos to spare bandwidth
- Upload to multiple sites
- ...

Comment: Browsers can't use maximum capasities of upload speed of connection, because of this softwares can upload faster than browser. So, i need this software, too :)

Comment: @Eray Alakese: The upload bandwidth is the limit, not the browser. It is normally much lower than for download.

Comment: Pennf0lio edited question after bounty :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many tools, mostly commercial are listed in :

[Digital Distribution Made Easy](http://www.thedvshow.com/digital-distribution-made-easy/)
[Upload Videos To Multiple Video Sharing Sites](http://www.reelseo.com/upload-multiple-sites/)

The ones which are maybe (still) free from the first link are :

> 1. [FireUploader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4724):( aka Universal Uploader) is an add-on for Firefox
>      that lets you upload multiple files to
>      your favorite websites, among them is
>      YouTube.
> 2. [HeySpread](http://heyspread.com/): tracking, an API, and they also have the ability to
>      export and syndicate videos that you
>      have already posted up on Youtube.
> 3. [Shozu](http://www.shozu.com/portal/index.do): allows you to upload photos and videos to sites like
>      Facebook, YouTube, Flickr, Google
>      Picasa, Faces, Buzznet, Kodak
>      EasyShare Gallery, Webshots,
>      Moblog.uk, Dada.net, Pikeo, Faces.com,
>      blip.tv and Cellfish. Shozu also
>      supports personal blogging sites like
>      Google Blogger, LiveJournal, TypePad,
>      Vox, WordPress, Windows Live Spaces
>      and citizen journalism sites like CNN
>      and BBC. You can also send photos and
>      videos to online storage service
>      Box.net as well to any email address
>      or FTP site.
> 4. [TrafficGeyser](http://www.trafficgeyser.com/): does more than broadcast video to 35 video-sharing
>      sites, Its a comprehensive service
>      that offers slidecasting, bonus
>      royalty-free music packs, toll-free
>      numbers to record podcasts or
>      testimonials, video-to-audio
>      conversion, broadcasting to podcast
>      directories and social bookmarking
>      sites. Free trial with subscription @
>      $97/month.
> 5. [TubeMogul](http://www.tubemogul.com/): Free with optional Premium option that offers improved
>      metrics, extra features and more.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is this: http://lifehacker.com/#!5568817/five-really-handy-google-command-line-tricks

Not a scheduler on its own, nor is it compatible with anything but google's services. However, you can easily create a batch file or bash script to to upload as many videos at a time as you wish, as well as scheduling the batch/bash file itself within Windows' Task Scheduler or linux's cron.